# Redux async call with then does not wait for api response

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm defining a Redux service to call an api endpoint:

```
export const TrackersApi = {
    getBasicsTrackers: async (): Promise<ReturnType<typeof recreator>> => {
        const url = "/api/getbasictrackers"
        const {data, statusText} = await axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
        if(statusText !== 'OK' && statusText !== 'No Content') throw new Error('Wrong response from getbasictrackers')
        const result = recreator(data) 
        console.log({result})
        return result
    },
```

The log returns the json response.

Then I inject this in a component on mount:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    store.dispatch(getBasicTrackers()).then(() => {
        
        if(this.props.trackers) {
            this.setState({
                sortedAndFilteredTrackers : this.props.trackers
            })
        }
        if(this.props.folders) {
            this.setState({
                sortedAndFilteredFolders: this.props.folders
            })
        }

        console.log('trackers', this.props.trackers)
    })
    
}
```

However the log here returns an empty array. I tried first without the then and I had the same issue.
How can I make it so that the `setState` is called only once the API response is received?

Additional info: This props is then used to fill in a table. However the table remains empty, which is the key issue here
It is mapped through this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ReduxStore.State) => ({
    trackers: state.trackersData.rawTrackers ? Object.values(state.trackersData.rawTrackers).map(item => ({...item, checked: false})) : [],
    folders: state.trackersData?.folders ? Object.values(state.trackersData.folders).map((folder: any) => ({...folder.summary, checked: false})) : []
})
```

Comment: `dispatch` just dispatches. If the store is correctly connected you don’t need to do anything; the props will update when the store is updated, at an arbitrary time in the future.

Comment: hmmm ok, should I use return or dispatch in my service function?